# image map highlighting of associated areas stops working when I take inline code into an external subroutine

Tags: javascript, arrays, imagemap, dhtml

I have 4 modules that dynamically produce PNG color imagemaps.   All 4 work as designed including highlighting sets of colormap areas (e.g. state counties) whose value/rate measure data are organized into quartiles.

There is a block of inline code shared by all 4.  The block produces an array of 4 elements (name it 'rels').  The elements may each contain a string of area names separated by commas.  The area names of an element correspond to areas whose value/rate measure data fell in that quartile of a range quartile structure.

When I take the shared inline code block and put it into an external subroutine, the highlighting mentioned above quits working in 3 of the 4 modules.  Using the 'Inspect Element' of 1 of the browsers I'm building for, I've verified that the inline code and the subroutine produces the same results in all four modules and that the  tags where the 4 elements of that rels array are used (rel='rels[0]') have the correct content in the respective rels element.

I use mapper.js to do the highlighting of both individual areas and area sets.  Its always worked very well.  The individual area highlighting continues to work in all 4 modules when I put the code block in the subroutine, but the highlighting of sets of areas stops in 3 of the 4 modules, as I said above.  I put the block I put in the subroutine back inline and the highlighting works again.  I put the code block back into the external subroutine and the highlighting of the 4 sets of areas quits working again.

Its like the  tag, where the rels array is used, can't see it any more when it is returned from the subroutine, even though it is there.  I actually return a pointer and use that to get the array and that works as expected.  The array of 4 elements of colormap areas are returned from the subroutine correctly in all 4 modules, and the areas in each of the 4 elements are the same as when the code block is inline.

I'd like to understand this better.  I'm not sure how to proceed.  I've written quite a few external subroutines for this application that return arrays and hashes that are used in the imagemap code with no problems.  I'm feeling sort of stuck on this one at the moment.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

craigt

Following is the inline block from 1 of the modules, the subroutine invocation, the subroutine, and the image map process where the rels array is used.  Language is Perl.

inline block:

```
@rels = ();
  $rels[0] = '';$rels[1] = '';$rels[2] = '';$rels[3] = '';
  $lowqtile = '';   
  foreach $key (@counties) {

    $keyhld = $key;
    $key = lc($key);
    $dval = $cdvals{$key};

    if (defined $cdvals{$key}) { # Has a value.

      if ($direct eq 'i') {        

        if ($dval <= $q1) {
          $rels[0] .= $key . ','; # List of areas in this quartile.
          $lowqtile .= $keyhld . ':';
          $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[3];
        } elsif ($dval > $q1 && $dval <= $q2) {
            $rels[1] .= $key . ',';
            $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[2];
          } elsif ($dval > $q2 && $dval <= $q3) {
              $rels[2] .= $key . ',';
              $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[1];
            } else {
                $rels[3] .= $key . ',';
                $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[0]; # > $q3 - best.
              }               

      } elsif ($direct eq 'd') {          

          if ($dval >= $q1) {
            $rels[0] .= $key . ',';
            $lowqtile .= $keyhld . ':';
            $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[3];
          } elsif ($dval >= $q2 && $dval < $q1) {
              $rels[1] .= $key . ',';
              $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[2];
            } elsif ($dval >= $q3 && $dval < $q2) {
                $rels[2] .= $key . ',';
                $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[1];
              } else {
                  $rels[3] .= $key . ',';
                  $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[0]; # < $q3 - best.
                }          

        } else {            
           
            if ($dval >= $q3 || $dval < -$q3) {
              $rels[0] .= $key . ',';
              $lowqtile .= $keyhld . ':';
              $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[3];
            } elsif (($dval>=$q2 && $dval<$q3)||($dval<=-$q2 && $dval>-$q3)) {
                $rels[1] .= $key . ',';
                $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[2];
              } elsif (($dval>=$q1 && $dval<$q2)||($dval<=-$q1 && $dval>-$q2)) {
                  $rels[2] .= $key . ',';
                  $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[1];
                } else {
                    $rels[3] .= $key . ',';
                    $ccolors{$key}=$colors2[0]; # < $q1 || > -$q1 - best.
                  }             

          } # Goal. 

    } else {
        $ccolors{$key} = 'white'; # NA.
      }

  } # foreach.

  $i = 0;
  foreach $key (@rels) {    
    if (index($key,',') > -1) {
      $rels[$i] = substr($rels[$i],0,length($rels[$i])-1);
    }     
    $i++;
  }

  $lowqtile = substr($lowqtile,0,length($lowqtile)-1); # Strip last colon.
```

subroutine invocation:

```
# Set the base level rels array (used in quartile area coloring), the low quartile string of keys in that quartile used to color colormap data, and color code by key.

($lowqtile, $relsPtr, $cclrPtr) = gtclrStf($direct, $q1, $q2, $q3, $q4, \@counties, \%cdvals, \@colors2); # Preferred behavior, quartile bounds, and county, data, quartile colors in.
@rels = @$relsPtr; # Get array/hash from references.
%ccolors = %$cclrPtr; # Color codes by area.
```

subroutine:

```
sub gtclrStf {

  my ($lowqtilex, $keyx, $keyhldx, $directx, $areasPtr, $avalsPtr, $qclrsPtr); # Scalars.

  my ($dvalx, $q1x, $q2x, $q3x, $q4x, $ix); # Numerics.

  my (@relsx, %aClrs, @areas, %avals, @qClrs); # Arrays/hashes.

  ($directx, $q1x, $q2x, $q3x, $q4x, $areasPtr, $avalsPtr, $qclrsPtr) = @_;
  @areas = @$areasPtr; # Get arrays from references.
  %avals = %$avalsPtr; 
  @qClrs = @$qclrsPtr;
  

  @relsx = ();
  $relsx[0] = '';$relsx[1] = '';$relsx[2] = '';$relsx[3] = '';
  $lowqtilex = '';   
  foreach $keyx (@areas) {

    $keyhldx = $keyx;
    $keyx = lc($keyx);
    $dvalx = $avals{$keyx};

    if (defined $avals{$keyx}) { # Has a value.

      if ($directx eq 'i') {        

        if ($dvalx <= $q1x) {
          $relsx[0] .= $keyx . ','; # List of areas in this quartile - used in area grouping.  
          $lowqtilex .= $keyhldx . ':'; # Used in colormap data highlighting.
          $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[3];
        } elsif ($dvalx > $q1x && $dvalx <= $q2x) {
            $relsx[1] .= $keyx . ',';
            $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[2];
          } elsif ($dvalx > $q2x && $dvalx <= $q3x) {
              $relsx[2] .= $keyx . ',';
              $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[1];
            } else {
                $relsx[3] .= $keyx . ',';
                $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[0]; # > $q3x - best.
              }               

      } elsif ($directx eq 'd') {          

          if ($dvalx >= $q1x) {
            $relsx[0] .= $keyx . ',';
            $lowqtilex .= $keyhldx . ':';
            $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[3];
          } elsif ($dvalx >= $q2x && $dvalx < $q1x) {
              $relsx[1] .= $keyx . ',';
              $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[2];
            } elsif ($dvalx >= $q3x && $dvalx < $q2x) {
                $relsx[2] .= $keyx . ',';
                $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[1];
              } else {
                  $relsx[3] .= $keyx . ',';
                  $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[0]; # < $q3x - best.
                }          

        } else {            
           
            if ($dvalx >= $q3x || $dvalx < -$q3x) {
              $relsx[0] .= $keyx . ',';
              $lowqtilex .= $keyhldx . ':';
              $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[3];
            } elsif (($dvalx >= $q2x && $dvalx < $q3x) || ($dvalx <= -$q2x && $dvalx > -$q3x)) {
                $relsx[1] .= $keyx . ',';
                $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[2];
              } elsif (($dvalx >= $q1x && $dvalx < $q2x) || ($dvalx <= -$q1x && $dvalx > -$q2x)) {
                  $relsx[2] .= $keyx . ',';
                  $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[1];
                } else {
                    $relsx[3] .= $keyx . ',';
                    $aClrs{$keyx}=$qClrs[0]; # < $q1 || > -$q1 - best.
                  }             

          } # Goal. 

    } else {
        $aClrs{$keyx} = 'white'; # NA.
      }

  } # foreach.

  $ix = 0;
  foreach $keyx (@relsx) { # Eliminate trailing comma if there.    
    if (index($keyx,',') > -1) {
      $relsx[$ix] = substr($relsx[$ix],0,length($relsx[$ix])-1);
    }   
    $ix++;
  }  

  $lowqtilex = substr($lowqtilex,0,length($lowqtilex)-1); # Strip last colon.

  return $lowqtilex, \@relsx, \%aClrs; # Return array of keys in each quartile pointer, low quartile keys string, and colors array by area pointer.

}
```

imagemap process where the rels array is used (1st 4 area tags).

```
print"<DIV STYLE='POSITION:absolute;LEFT:$rpos;'><IMG SRC='$filex' WIDTH='600' HEIGHT='265' USEMAP='#cmap' STYLE='POSITION:absolute;LEFT:$rpos;' CLASS='mapper $cmabrdr iopacity$colrmapcolr9 icolor$colrmapcolr8'></DIV>\n";
  print"<MAP NAME='cmap'>\n";

  if (!$simflg) {        
    print"<AREA shape='circle' CLASS='$cmabrdr iopacity$colrmapcolr9 icolor$colrmapcolr1' ID='q1' rel='$rels[3]' TITLE='quartile 1' HREF='#' coords='555,50,8'>
          <AREA shape='circle' CLASS='$cmabrdr iopacity$colrmapcolr9 icolor$colrmapcolr2' ID='q2' rel='$rels[2]' TITLE='quartile 2' HREF='#' coords='565,70,8'>
          <AREA shape='circle' CLASS='$cmabrdr iopacity$colrmapcolr9 icolor$colrmapcolr3' ID='q3' rel='$rels[1]' TITLE='quartile 3' HREF='#' coords='575,90,8'>
          <AREA shape='circle' CLASS='$cmabrdr iopacity$colrmapcolr9 icolor$colrmapcolr4' ID='q4' rel='$rels[0]' TITLE='quartile 4' HREF='#' coords='585,110,8'>
          \n";
  }  
  
  $gstr = '';
  foreach $key ( @counties ) {

    $keylc = lc($key);
    $surtok = 'x' . $keylc;
    $surtok =~ s/ +//g;
    $uckey = $key;
    $uckey =~ s/\b(\w)(\w*)/uc($1).lc($2)/ge; # Uppercase 1st word letters.   

    if (!$simflg) {
      if (defined $cdvals{$keylc}) { 
        print"<AREA ID='$key' HREF='$curls{$keylc}' SHAPE='POLY' COORDS='$ccoords{$keylc}' TITLE='$keystr{$keylc} -\r\nClick For The $uckey $blev $dcname Trend' ONMOUSEOVER=\"showIt('$surtok');setStatus(' ');\" ONMOUSEOUT=\"hideIt('$surtok');setStatus(' ');\">\n";   
      } else {
          print"<AREA ID='$key' SHAPE='POLY' COORDS='$ccoords{$keylc}' TITLE='$keystr{$keylc}' ONMOUSEOVER=\"setStatus(' ');\" ONMOUSEOUT=\"setStatus(' ');\">\n";
        }
    } else {
        print"<AREA ID='$key' SHAPE='POLY' COORDS='$ccoords{$keylc}' TITLE='$keystr{$keylc}' ONMOUSEOVER=\"setStatus(' ');\" ONMOUSEOUT=\"setStatus(' ');\">\n";   
      }
    
    if (!$simflg && defined $cdvals{$keylc}) {    
      $j = allSame(1, $vlus{$surtok});        
      $k = allSame(2, $rts{$surtok});         
      
      if (exists($vlus{$surtok})) {
        $gstr .= "<DIV ID='$surtok'><A ONMOUSEOVER=\"setStatus('Value and Rate Trends');\" ONMOUSEOUT=\"setStatus('  ');\"><SPAN ID='slhdr$surtok' STYLE='POSITION:absolute;TOP:28.5%;LEFT:$lpos;FONT-SIZE:9px;BACKGROUND-COLOR:#$ltappbgcolr;FONT-FAMILY:arial;'>$uckey v/r Trends<BR></SPAN><SPAN ID='slx$surtok' STYLE='POSITION:absolute;TOP:$tpos;LEFT:$lpos;BACKGROUND-COLOR:#$ltappbgcolr;BORDER:1px dashed lightgray;PADDING-TOP:$tpads;'>&nbsp;<SPAN CLASS='inlinesparkline$j' TITLE='Value Trend' ONMOUSEOVER=\"setStatus('Value Trend');\" ONMOUSEOUT=\"setStatus(' ');\">$vlus{$surtok}</SPAN>&nbsp;&nbsp;<SPAN CLASS='inlinesparkline$k' TITLE='Rate Trend' ONMOUSEOVER=\"setStatus('Rate Trend');\" ONMOUSEOUT=\"setStatus(' ');\">$rts{$surtok}</SPAN>&nbsp;</SPAN></A></DIV><SCRIPT>hideIt('$surtok');</SCRIPT>";              
      }
    }     

  } 

  print"</MAP>\n";
```

As I said above, I've verified that the contents of the rels array is the same at the area tags where the array is used coming from the inline code block and subroutine in all 4 modules.   And the highlighting of area sets works in all 4 modules with the inline block.   I put the inline block into subroutine and pass the array out of the routine with a pointer/reference, and the highlighting of area sets no longer works in 3 of the 4 modules.

Following is a link that runs off a server at my home.   It is the 1 module that works with the code in subroutine.   You can see the area set highlighting by mousing over any of the 4 circles over right of the colormap.

[colormap example with subroutine where highlighting works](http://steepusa.no-ip.info/scx/careaNEW.cgi?str=SKY_healthy%20births_Total%20in%20KY%20Counties2_healthy!zl_healthy_none_level3_0_1_0_none_none)

All data are for test purposes ONLY.

Update: I'm frustrated.  I've tried quite a few things and have not been able to move the ball on this.  I've compared the module that works where the area sets highlighting works when the rels array comes out of an external subroutine with the 3 that don't in that configuration. And I've looked at the 3 modules where the area sets highlighting quits working when the rels array comes out of an external subroutine and works when the subroutine is brought inline.  I've listed what I know following.

1. Although all 4 modules are alike in many ways, there are significant differences.  But I don't think any of these difference could impact area sets highlighting in the 3 modules where this behavior does not work.
2. The 3 modules that don't work have maybe 10 other subroutines passing  scalars. arrays, and hashes in and out that work.
3. For the 3 modules where the area sets highlighting quits working when the rels array comes out of an external subroutine and works when the subroutine is brought inline, the rels array content is identical for all three modules in both configurations.
4. The rels array is not touched between where it emerges from the subroutine (or inline code) and where is is used in the 1st 4 area tag sets of the image map.
5. The area map image and area html is exactly the same in all 4 modules in the subroutine configuration except the name of the image map, the circle coordinates that a user hovers over to see the area sets highlighting, and the areas in the rels array elements that correspond to the colored quartiles.
6. The hover over links (circles) that do the area sets highlighting are all active links in all 3 modules in the subroutine configuration, but no highlighting occurs of the sets of areas when I mouse over.
7. The hover over behavior of individual areas continues to work in all 3 modules in the subroutine configuation.

I would like to figure this out.  I guess I could say well at least it works in the inline configuration, but that is not the way this is supposed to work.  I'm not seeing it, but I'm still looking.   Any suggestion on anything about this will be appreciated.

Thanks for your time.
craigt

Comment: Please share your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: kmoser, I'm having trouble adding code.  The language is Perl.   For some reason, it splits the code up.  It puts part of it before a scrollable area, part in the scrollable area, and part after.   I've tried {} and <pre><code> and cntl K several times.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For simplicity, type a line with three backticks at the beginning, then on the next line paste your code, then on the next line type three backticks. For more options see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

I have had some other priorities that kept me away from this problem for awhile, having something that worked in place.  I thought that the problem must be something incorrect in the 5 where the set of areas highlighting did not work and that something must have been ok in the 1 that did work.  The problem here was mismatched hash keys.   I have 9 hashes in each of the six modules involved in this problem.  All keys matched across hashes in the 1 module where the set of areas highlighting worked.  The other 5 modules had 1 hash with mismatched keys.  And it took me awhile to see it and my problem description reflected my lack of understanding.  All 6 modules are working correctly now.  Thanks to everyone who look at this.  This problem is closed.